# How can I properly programmatically add custom views to a view group in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to implement a horizontal scroll views that adds custom written cardviews based on information in a room database. I also add a text view to space out the card views as configuring the padding in XML and programmatically both did not work. The problem is that whenever I create a new "artist" in the database, which should then add a card to the scroll view, there is a chance that the text view for spacing gets added to the incorrect side of the card view. Also there is a chance that card views get repeated and in this case the text view for spacing doesn't  get added at all.

If you need the github repository to see the effects yourself, you can clone it here https://github.com/jeremyohandley/PosTattoo

I've tried changing adding log statements in various places and checking the database to see if there is any repeated data or missing data. I'm not sure what the source of the error is.

Artist Page Fragment.kt

```
package com.jeremy.ohandley.postattoo

import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import com.jeremy.ohandley.postattoo.db.Artist
import com.jeremy.ohandley.postattoo.db.ArtistDao
import com.jeremy.ohandley.postattoo.db.Customer
import com.jeremy.ohandley.postattoo.db.database
import org.w3c.dom.Text


class ArtistPageFragment : Fragment() {

    private var db: database? = null
    private var artistDao: ArtistDao? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        db = database.getInstance(activity!!.applicationContext)
        artistDao = db!!.artistDAO()

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artist_page, container, 
false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val addArtist = view!!.findViewById<ImageButton> 
   (R.id.add_artist_button)
            addArtist.setOnClickListener { launchNewArtistDialog() }
            loadArtists()
        }

    private fun launchNewArtistDialog() {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)
        val builderView = 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_artist_dialog, null)
        initAddArtistDialogButtons(builder, builderView)

        builder.setView(builderView)
        builder.show()
    }

    private fun initAddArtistDialogButtons(builder: AlertDialog.Builder, 
builderView: View) {
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(context, "Artist not created", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        builder.setPositiveButton("Create Artist") { _, _ ->

            val firstNameInput = builderView.findViewById<EditText> 
   (R.id.first_name_input)
                 val lastNameInput = builderView.findViewById<EditText> 
   (R.id.last_name_input)
            val emailInput = builderView.findViewById<EditText> 
   (R.id.email_input)
            val phoneNumberInput = builderView.findViewById<EditText> 
   (R.id.phone_number_input)
            val firstName = firstNameInput.text.toString()
            val lastName = lastNameInput.text.toString()
            val email = emailInput.text.toString()
            val phoneNumber = phoneNumberInput.text.toString()

            val newArtist = Artist(null, firstName, lastName, email, 
phoneNumber)
            artistDao!!.insertArtist(newArtist)
            loadArtists()

        }


    }

    private fun loadArtists() {
        val artists = artistDao!!.getArtists()
        clearArtists()

        artists.forEach {

            val card = ArtistCard(context!!)
            val name = "${it.firstName} ${it.lastName}"
            card.setName(name)
            card.setNumber(it.phoneNumber)
            card.setEmail(it.email)
            card.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4)
            addToLayout(card)

        }
    }

    private fun clearArtists() {
        val cardLL = view!!.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.cardLL)

        for (i in 1 until cardLL.childCount) {
            cardLL.removeView(cardLL.getChildAt(i))
        }
    }

    private fun addToLayout(card: ArtistCard) {
        val spacerView = TextView(context)
        val cardLL = view!!.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.cardLL)
        cardLL.addView(card)
        cardLL.addView(spacerView)
        spacerView.layoutParams = 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(convertDpToPx(context!!, 8f).toInt(), 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

    }

    private fun convertDpToPx(context: Context, dp: Float): Float {
        return dp * context.resources.displayMetrics.density
    }



}
```

Artist Page Fragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ArtistPageFragment"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/artists_linear_layout"
>

        <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/scroll_view"

        >
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/cardLL"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:gravity="center"
            >


                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                >

                    <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/add_artist_button"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
                    />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>-

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

ArtistCard.kt (custom card)

```
package com.jeremy.ohandley.postattoo

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.TextView

class ArtistCard(context: Context) : CardView(context) {
    var attributes:AttributeSet? = null

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : this(context) {
        attributes = attrs
    }



    init{
        inflate(context, R.layout.artist_card, this)

        val name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.artist_name)
        val number = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.artist_phone_number)
        val email = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.artist_email)

        val attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributes, 
R.styleable.ArtistCard)
        name.text = attributes.getString(R.styleable.ArtistCard_name)
        number.text = attributes.getString(R.styleable.ArtistCard_number)
        email.text = attributes.getString(R.styleable.ArtistCard_email)
        attributes.recycle()
    }

    fun setName (mName:String){
        val name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.artist_name)
        name.text = mName
    }

    fun setNumber (mNumber:String){
        val number = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.artist_phone_number)
        number.text = mNumber
    }

    fun setEmail (mEmail:String){
        val email = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.artist_email)
        email.text = mEmail
    }
}
```

Artist Card Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"


>


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
    >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Name"

        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="sample name"
                android:id="@+id/artist_name"

        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Phone Number"

        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="(1)-555-555-5555"
                android:id="@+id/artist_phone_number"

        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Email"

        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="sample@gmail.com"
                android:id="@+id/artist_email"

        />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: remove android:layoutDirection="rtl"

Comment: @AlbertoCappellina the direction is intended to be rtl.

Comment: then you should remove from the last-1 to 0. this will keep the add button